# Index on a TEXT column with defined set of values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> describe marketing_details;
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------- 
------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | 
Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------- 
------------+-----------------------------+
| id                       | bigint(20)          | NO   | PRI | NULL              
| auto_increment              |
| platform_origin          | varchar(100)        | NO   | MUL |                   
|                             |
| partner_id               | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                 
|                             |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+------- 
------------+-----------------------------+
```

For a query like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM partners
INNER JOIN marketing_details ON partners.id = marketing_details.partner_id
where marketing_details.platform_origin IN ('platform_A', 'platform_B');
```

The `platform_origin` column can have a set of defined values (one of 4 values). So adding index/full text index does not seem to be of use here. But the data can be huge and there can be multiple constraints in the query. What will be a good way to optimise the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM partners p INNER JOIN
     marketing_details md
     ON p.id = md.partner_id 
WHERE md.platform_origin IN ('platform_A', 'platform_B');
```

You should try indexes on:

- `marketing_details(platform_origin, partner_id)`
- `partners(id)`

You probably already have the second one if `id` is declared as the primary key.

Comment: According to the description, in your first index `partner_id` is much more selective than `platform_origin`. I would switch the order of the columns in that index.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion would be to have a check constraint on platform_origin to have only the 4 possible values

Also it would help if you have histograms on the column platform_origin if your version allows. This would give the optimizer more inputs while creating an optimal plan if there is data skew on the values in the column.

Have a look at the following link.

https://mysqlserverteam.com/histogram-statistics-in-mysql/